# Problem storing sorted images order in the Database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am having a little problem and I hope that someone can help me out:

So, I am trying to sort images and save the order in the DB, I can set the new order with `JS` and send it with `AJAX` to the controller and then to the model, this last one doesn't give any error or so, but for some reason is not saving the order, maybe someone here could see what I am not x), so here is the code (NOTE: I just put the code for sorting images and skipped the main classes just leaving the functions, to make it clear and not showing unnecessary things, however if you need more details, please let me know (= )

Thanks in advance (=.

**JS**

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('#desul li').length; i++)
{
   almacenarOrdenId[i] = event.target.children[i].id;
   ordenItem[i] = i+1;
}

$('#btnDesignPortSave').click(function(){

for(var i = 0; i < $('#desul li').length; i++)
{
    var actualizarOrden = new FormData();
    actualizarOrden.append("actualizarOrdenGaleria", almacenarOrdenId[i]);
    actualizarOrden.append("actualizarOrdenItem", ordenItem[i]);

    $.ajax({

        url:"PATH TO AJAX FILE",
        method: "POST",
        data: actualizarOrden,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(respuesta)
        {
            $('#desport ul').html(respuesta);

            swal("Order updated", {
                buttons: false,
                timer: 2000,
            }).then(
                function(){
                    window.location = "designPortfolio";
                }
            );
          }
      })//ajax
   }//for

})//Btn
```

**AJAX FILE**

```
public $actualizarOrdenGaleria;
public $actualizarOrdenItem;

public function actualizarDordenAjax()
{

    $datos = array("ordenGaleria" => $this -> actualizarOrdenGaleria,
                    "ordenItem" => $this -> actualizarOrdenItem);

    $respuesta = gestorDgaleriaController::actualizarOrdenController($datos);

    echo $respuesta;

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////

if(isset($POST["actualizarOrdenGaleria"]))
{
   $c = new Ajax();
   $c -> actualizarOrdenGaleria = $_POST["actualizarOrdenGaleria"];
   $c -> actualizarOrdenItem = $_POST["actualizarOrdenItem"];
   $c -> actualizarDordenAjax();

}
```

**PHP**

```
////CONTROLLER

public function actualizarOrdenController($datos)
{
    gestorDgaleriaModel::actualizarOrdenModel($datos,"DB TABLE");
    $respuesta = gestorDgaleriaModel::seleccionarOrdenModel("DB TABLE");

    foreach($respuesta as $row => $item)
    {
        echo'<li id="'.$item["id"].'" class="bloqueDGaleria">
                <i class="fa fa-times delbtn portdesdel" aria-hidden="true" ruta="'.$item["ruta"].'"></i>
                <a data-fancybox="portdes" href="'.substr($item["ruta"],6).'">
                    <img src="'.substr($item["ruta"],6).'" class="handleDImg"/>
                </a>
            </li>';


    }

}

////MODEL

public function actualizarOrdenModel($datos,$tabla)
{
    $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET orden = :orden WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt -> bindParam(":orden", $datos["ordenItem"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":id", $datos["ordenGaleria"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        return "ok";
    }
    else
    {
        return "error";
    }

    $stmt -> close();


}


public function seleccionarOrdenModel($tabla)
{
    $stmt = conexion::conectar()-> prepare("SELECT id, ruta FROM $tabla ORDER BY orden ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fecthAll();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: is your ajax file actually sending something? You can check for example in chrome, when you execute the function, via the tab "network" in the develop tool if a call is made and what data is send, and what it receives. If the data is correct what is send, then you have to look into your controller. Next to that, i am not sure if you changed that, but your post url is set to `url:"PATH TO AJAX FILE",` You might wanna set that to a real URL ;)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, the ajax file is indeed sending something i checked as you mentioned, and my post url has the real path is just i didn't want to post it here and make it public.

Thanks again =D